# How to convert the MATLAB GUI *.m file generated by GUIDE's export tool back to a *.fig file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

As described : https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2011/04/04/guide-guis-in-all-one-file/, it's possible to export a GUI *.fig file (and it's *.m file) to a single *.m file, which is very useful for version controlling a project (fig files are compiled).

However, the generated/exported single *.m file is not easy to edit again if you need to do more changes to the GUI. Is there a way to convert that file back to the *.fig and *.m files, or import that single *.m into GUIDE, so that it can be editable there?

Comment: 1) Run the `.m` file. 2) Save the figure as `.fig`. 3) Open `.fig` in GUIDE. Personally, I'd just stick with the `.m` file (or better yet, make a new one without all the GUIDE nonsense). You can also [convert](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66087) it to a `uifigure` and use the `appdesigner`.